# Loop through files in current folder and rename them based on greater or smaller

Tags: batch-file

I need to change multiple files names based on its name.

I have files named like this.

```
001.mp3
002.mp3
003.mp3
004.mp3
005.mp3
...etc
```

What I was trying using a Windows batch file.

```
@echo off
for %%I in (*.*) do (if %~0 gtr 010 ren %%I ???-new.*)
```

What I'm trying to do here is:

> "For" ---> to loop through
>   
> "in (*.*)" ---> in current folder where batch file has been created
>   
> "if %~0 gtr 010" ---> if the file name greater than 010
>   
> "ren %%I ???-new.*" ---> rename that file to be "010-new.mp3"

That is what I have tried to do but it needs to be fixed, please help me.

Comment: You are off to a good start. You will need to split off the number from the filename in order to compare it. Use `FOR /?` to see how to get the file name without the extension.

Comment: You are aware that the batch file itself is `%0` aren't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the given naming pattern (`XXX.mp3`), it's quite easy:

```
for %%i in (*.mp3) do if %%~ni gtr 010 echo ren %%i %%~ni-new%%~xi
```

Comment: please help me with this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55357492/how-to-use-if-statement-with-multiple-condition-in-windows-batch-files]